# FancyBox subject not appearing centered on WebOS devices

Tags: fancybox, webos

I'm building a mobile website using [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net), which works fine on all Android devices I've thrown at it and all iPhones, but has a problem on webOS devices.

When my subject pops up in FancyBox, it's supposed to be centered in the the viewbox of my device, but on webOS, the subject is at the top of the page.

This causes a problem when a user clicks on a subject at the bottom of my webpage and then has to scroll all the way to to the top to see it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that scrollLeft and scrollTop values of the page aren't updated on webOS when you scroll in the page.  This is because internally, the page is rendering as one large image and the WebView used by the browser is just panning around on that image.  The FancyBox code uses those properties to adjust the top/left CSS values of the box when it's displayed.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I'll have to figure something else out.